# Infowindow not opening over marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm trying to get markerclusters to work with a sidebar.

I have tried this: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html

but I am having the same issue that the infowindow is not opening over the marker, when the link is clicked.

Can anyone help with this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have two more things happen when they click on the side bar.  You want to pan to that location, and you want to set the zoom at an appropriate level so you can actually see the marker.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
```

could be changed to

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.panTo(marker.position);
    map.setZoom(13);
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
```

This allows the map to travel to the marker and make it visible, before it displays the info window.

Answer (score 1):

That functionality (automatically zooming the map to show the infowindow) got broken in the current [experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning), I have update that example to use the release version (v=3).

I changed the URL below (which doesn't specify a version, and therefore gets the experimental version, v=3.exp):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

To this URL (specifies v=3):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3"></script>
```

And [it is working again](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html).